# Extracting parts of string with specific limits

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a small problem. My string has the following format;

```
{"version":"5.14.1","id":"ABCD","key":"266",...... etc
```

I want to get the ABCD after "id" and this is what I have tried

I tried

```
string[] output;
output = Regex.Matches(site,"(?<=(?:\"id\")\:\")([^\"]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

but when I try to compile it says "unrecognized escape sequence" for the colon after id.

The Regex Expression that I used that worked is:

```
(?<=(?:"id")\:")([^"]+)
```

But I'm not sure how to put it inside the Regex.Matches (I tried to put \ before " but it says unrecognized escape sequence)

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a JSON parser?

Comment: I want to stay away from that for now, but I figured it out. I just need to add a \ before the \:" in the regex expression

Answer (score 0):

The regex error is right -- `:` is not a special character within a regular expression (except contextually in e.g. `(?:)` groups), so it can't be escaped. (Note that there's two levels of escaping going on here: when `\:` is seen within a C# string, the C# compiler decides that `:` isn't special and so silently leaves it be with a literal backslash preceding it; then, the regex engine tries to interpret it and generates the error.)

A regex that does what you want (for the sample string, anyway) is:

```
"\"id\":\"([^\"]+)"
```

But I suggest using a proper parser, since this looks suspiciously like JSON. Regular expressions are convenient, but it assumes a lot about the input to use one here (e.g. there could be data like `{'foo':'"id":"hmm"',"id": "realid"...`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a Regular expression to attempt to parse JSON, it's not going to cover all scenarios, and you are just fighting against something that should be easy.

Either create a class to house the properties you need:

```
 class MyData { 
   public string Version { get; set; }
   public string Id { get; set; }
   ...
 }
```

Install the NuGet package Newtonsoft JSON: `install-package Newtonsoft.Json`

```
string myData = "{\"version\":\"5.14.1\",\"id\":\"ABCD\" }";

MyData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(myData);
Dictionary<string, string> dataAsDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(myData);
string abcd = data.Id;
abcd = dataAsDictionary["id"];
```

If you use the `Dictionary` approach you won't need a class, but it's not strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to process the string using a regex? If the string will always hold correctly-formed JSON then it would be quicker, easier and less error-prone to use [a purpose-built JSON parser](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string yourString = "{\"version\":\"5.14.1\",\"id\":\"ABCD\",\"key\":\"266\"}";    // etc

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourString);
Console.WriteLine(json.id);    // displays ABCD
```

Answer (score -1):

Got it

```
output = Regex.Matches(site,"(?<=(?:\"id\")\\:\")([^\"]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```